# Variance of imaginary part of a complex random variable.

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

$\def\im{\mathrm {im}}$
Let $\xi$ be a complex random variable. $\xi_\im$ is imaginary part of $\xi$. Obviously $E(\xi_{\im}) = \operatorname{Im}E(\xi)$. My question is how to compute $\operatorname{var}(\xi_{\im})$ given $\operatorname{var}(\xi)$?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you define the variance of $X$ as $E|X-EX|^2$ rather than $E(X-EX)^2$.  In the former case, you cannot recover the variance of the imaginary part.  Consider $X_1$ to any real valued random variable, and $X_2 = iX_1$.  Both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same variance, but the imaginary parts of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are different.

Comment: So, I need two values $E[(X - EX)^2]$ and $E[(X-EX)(\bar{X} - \bar{E(X)})]$ to recover imaginary part, right.

Comment: I would have to think about it.  It is a little too late at night for me to answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's subtract off the expected value, so it does not get in the way. Write $\xi=x+iy$. The variance of $\xi$ is $E(x^2)+E(y^2)$. As  Stephen Montgomery-Smith  already said, there is no way to get $E(y^2)$ from here (though you can estimate it from above).

But if you also know  $E(\xi^2)$, that  would be enough. In fact, just its real part suffices: the real part of $E(\xi^2)$  is $E(x^2)-E(y^2)$. 
$$ E(y^2)  =\frac12 (E(|\xi|^2)-\operatorname{Re}E(\xi^2))$$